# jQuery how to close dialog from iframe within dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, dialog

If I open a dialog like so:

```
$('<iframe id="externalSite" class="externalSite" src="http://www.example.com" />').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        resizable: true
    })
```

How can I close the dialog from withing the iframe?

Comment: I'd say the code inside doesn't have permissions for that, esp. if it's an external site.

Comment: @Piskor, its the same site. I can call a function on the parent window like `window.parent.function()` but not sure how I would target this dialog to close it.

Comment: Similar question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) it might help or point you in the right direction.

Comment: Worth noting that you might need to set the [document.domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain) property on the contained iFrame. This lets you share frame contexts between different subdomains on the same top level domain.

Comment: I just ran into this problem, and shook my head because two days ago my CLOSE button worked fine to close the parent dialog. "What's going on?" I thought. "It's on the same website!" Ah, but no: If I open my app from "mydomain.com", it calles the iframe src="www.mydomain.com". Notice the "www". It's not the same domain!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK so I put the iframe on the page with display set to none. I open it like this:

```
$('#externalSite').dialog({ ... });
```

on the main parent window I have a function like this:

```
function closeIframe()
{
    $('#externalSite').dialog('close');
    return false;
}
```

From within the iframe I call:

```
window.parent.closeIframe();
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem will happen when you open "http://mywebsite.com/myapp/" and the iframe source uses "www" (or vice versa, swapping the "www"). I strongly suspect the OP is doing something like that.

Comment: I am the OP, and this was 3 years ago :)

Comment: The other day I Googled a problem. I came to a StackOverflow page, and someone was saying, "I used Gregory Lewis's code, and it worked." I was going to leave a funny comment about another guy named Gregory Lewis, until I scrolled down the page, and saw he was talking about an answer I gave. I had the problem twice, and didn't even remember that I solved the problem last year that I was looking for an answer to yesterday.

Comment: Why is this answer not at the top? Btw this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

Simply calling the following worked for me:

window.parent.$('#externalSite').dialog('close');

Comment: Actually in my case, I was using Wijmo Dialog (built on jQuery UI) and so I had a dialog/popup loading external content (HTML) and needed a way to close the dialog/popup by pressing a "cancel" button inside that external HTML.. so the following worked nicely for me:

window.parent.$('#eventdialog').wijdialog('close');   so #eventdialog of course was my selector.  Within the close event of the wijmo dialog, you could then add any clean-up code too.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
$(window.parent).dialog('close');
```

I have never used the jQuery UI dialog, so I'm not sure that will actually work. It seems to me that you would need to maintain a reference to the dialog you created so that you can use it to close the dialog.

Note, you could also look for elements in the parent's DOM by:

```
$('#someParentDOMElement' , window.parent);
```

Of course, all of this is assuming that the site you load within the `iframe` is on the same domain as the parent document. If not, then the document in your `iframe` will not have access to the parent DOM at all.

Comment: I tried `$(window.parent).dialog('close');` it did not work but I took your maintain a reference idea and used it in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `$(window.parent).dialog('close')` doesn't work because `window.parent` refers to the parent JavaScript Window object, not the jQuery UI dialog element.