# Close IFRAME Window

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

The below jQuery get trigger by a button on a GridView which allow me to Edit the record in a nice popup Iframe.  However, I need to close the Iframe popup from behind code(c#) of the EditEmployee.aspx page.  I've try almost all the option by searching google and stackoverflow and none seems to be working.  I try add a function on the parent page call CloseDialog() and then call window.parent.CloseDialog() and I can't get it to work.  Can someone please help me, I'm new to jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#popup').on('click', function (e) {

            var page = $(this).attr("href")  //get url of link

            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 450,
                width: 'auto',
                title: "Edit Employee",
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () { $dialog.dialog('close'); }
                            },
                close: function (event, ui) {

                   __doPostBack('<%= btnRefresh.ClientID %>', '');  // To refresh gridview when user close dialog
                }
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
       <ItemTemplate >
           <a id="popup" href='EditEmployee.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID") %>' >edit</a>
     </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this on the server side?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live()` has been deprecated for many years.

Comment: I need to close the IFrame popup once the record has been saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out that I need to give me iframe a id and then call the close it function like this link [Close IFrame Dialog from Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575955/jquery-how-to-close-dialog-from-iframe-within-dialog)

```
function closeIframe()
{
$('#iframeId').dialog('close');
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "closeDialog", "$dialog.dialog('close');", true);
```