# The jQuery dialog doesn't closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The jQuery dialog cannot close when I call function to do instead of clicking the Cancel button. My page has two buttons which are Save and Cancel button. The Cancel button can close the dialog . Now I would like to close the dialog after saving the data;I don't want to refresh the parent page. I call the function in code behind. The function runs but didn't save the dialog box; it reload the page which opening in dialog .  Would someone tell me how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

My script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCancel').click(function (e) {                
            e.preventDefault();
            CloseDialog();
        });
    });

    function closeMe() {           
        e.preventDefault();
        CloseDialog();
    }


function CloseDialog() {   
   $('#jquery_box').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,     
    title: name,
    modal: true, 
  });

 $('#jquery_box').dialog('close');
}
```

There is my cancel button

```
<input  id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
```

There is my code behind to call the function

```
 Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "close", "closeMe();", True)
```

Comment: The function `closeMe()` is not accessible outside the scope of the ready handler.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I changed it as you suggest but it still didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to fix my problem for referencing to [jQuery how to close dialog from iframe within dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575955/jquery-how-to-close-dialog-from-iframe-within-dialog)
I put the webpage on the iframe inside the jQuery dialog box.